# Picasso error on loading image

Tags: android, android-sqlite, picasso

The problem is that the images are loading properly from the table,but logcat still shows me the error , what am I doing wrong ?

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) v.getTag();
        if (img == null) {
            img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageOrders);
        }
        Object url = ((Cursor) getItem(position)).getString(1);
        Log.d("PicassaURL",url.toString());
        String ol = url.toString();

        Picasso.with(v.getContext()).load(ol).placeholder(R.drawable.bay).into(img);
        //TextView titletxt= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        //titletxt.setTypeface(HelveticaBold);
        return v;
    }
```

The Logcat

```
    E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /http:/ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/512IKr3cnVL._SL160_.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    I/System.out﹕ resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/512IKr3cnVL._SL160_.jpg
    D/PICASSA STRING﹕ http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/512IKr3cnVL._SL160_.jpg
```

Comment: It seems that it cannot find the file from the Url, please double check, and what the logcat show form Log.d("PicassaURL",url.toString());?

Comment: the error is there , but the images are loading properly without a problem , i can't understand why is it showing if it works,i added the log

Comment: thank you for corecting the question

Comment: Not a problem. If you find my comment helpful, plz upvote it, thx

Comment: Are you sure it isn't loading from the cache ? You can easily see where the images are loaded from [using `setIndicatorsEnabled(true)`](https://square.github.io/picasso/).

Comment: after i set it , at first the images are red , then green,but still the error persists

Comment: Most likely the error logs are not output by picasso. You can comment out the picasso loading line to make sure of it. And even the debug string of the log you pasted doesn't match the code, so please make sure first of the actual code causing the error output.